# CSS hover issue on product-image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I got an issue while hovering an image. i need to overlap the image with bottom section.
heres the link
http://hg01.ispghosting.com/techashram/UIDev_Inhouse_2014/Vivekraj_KR/Html5/BibAndTucker/index.html

Comment: Increase the page bottom margin maybe? Not entirely sure what you're asking.

Comment: You want the hover image and buttons to sit on top of the images below, instead of bumping them down?  Just add `position:absolute` to the class You'll also need to set the z-index > 1 and add a background color/border to make the hover images stand out.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. "

Comment: when im trying to give position: absolute to the li tag it looks weired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the "border" off your li-tag and put it on your add_product.hover_visible then add some css to it perhaps something like this? Hope this will point you the right way:

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
display: block;
border: 1px solid red; /*This would be your shadow box effect*/
height: 350px; /* Probably set a different height here that works better */ 
margin-top: 0; /* This was just to remove a CSS rule you had */
```

It requires your li (or any close parent to this tag) to be `position: relative;` but when i entered these rules into your page it seemed to get an effect that was half way there to what you want I think. Good luck!

Comment: its almost done but the problem is that i need to give box shadow to the li tag.

Comment: @VIVEKRAJ Nice! Congratz. 
If you could mark as answered it would be great. More internet points for me :)